# Consolidate two state arrays in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays in `state`, I would look like the final `result` as follows

```
this.state = {
    one: [{ "month": "January", "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld1": "17", "fld2": "24" },
          { "month": "February", "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld1": "18", "fld2": "15" }],
    two: [{ "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld": "fld1", "val": "Profit" },
          { "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld": "fld2", "val": "Loss" },
          { "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld": "fld3", "val": "Total" }]
};
//code here
const result = [{ "month": "January", "Profit": "17", "Loss": "24" },
                { "month": "February", "Profit": "18", "Loss": "15" }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has barely anything to do with **React**. But anyway, here goes:

```js
this.state = {
    one: [{ "month": "January", "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld1": "17", "fld2": "24" },
          { "month": "February", "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld1": "18", "fld2": "15" }],
    two: [{ "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld": "fld1", "val": "Profit" },
          { "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld": "fld2", "val": "Loss" },
          { "reportCode": "XYZ", "fld": "fld3", "val": "Total" }]
};

const targetResult = [{ "month": "January", "Profit": "17", "Loss": "24" },
                { "month": "February", "Profit": "18", "Loss": "15" }];
                
const result = this.state.one.map(
  ({ month, reportCode, fld1, fld2 }) => {

      const key1 = this.state.two.find(({ fld }) => fld === 'fld1').val;
      const key2 = this.state.two.find(({ fld }) => fld === 'fld2').val;
      
      return {
        month,
        [key1]: fld1, 
        [key2]: fld2,
      };
   },
);

console.log('result: ', result);
console.log('is-correct: ', _.isEqual(result, targetResult));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think .map would be cleaner than .reduce, but otherwise this is it.